# Writing timestamps to a CSV file

Tags: r, csv

I want to write timestamp in output CSV file. Timestamp in format `"2013-08-28 01:02"`

Basically I want to write 3 parameters lets say `a`, `b` and `timestamp` in one output file. I am reading `a` and `b` from a data file (`in.nc`) and now want a output file (`out.csv`) which will have output like this:

```
2013-08-28 01:02,0.2,20

2013-08-28 02:02,0.1,30

2013-08-28 03:02,1,40

2013-08-28 03:02,4,80
```

I have no timestamp in input file and has to create one in program to write in output file.

Comment: may be you need to create a `data.frame` with 3 columns and use `write.table` or `write.csv`

Comment: i want to know how to write timestamp. i know i can try write.table or write.csv for writing things.....

Comment: You showed some data that is supposed to be `output` format.  What about your input dataset example?

Comment: input data is two column matrix with values like this: column 1(a): 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.8 and column 2(b): 20, 40, 50, 90

Comment: Regarding creating the time stamps, you should have some date time data, right?  Or do you want to create a time stamp from a particular date with specific intervals of time?

Comment: I dont have time in input, want to create it from a particular date with specific intervals of time

Comment: Okay then please show that info in your post about the particular date and interval.

Comment: Some `dput`s of your variables might help along with (perhaps) the first few lines of your data file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose, you want to create an one-hour interval data from `2013-08-28 01:02:00`

```
 #input data
 Input <- data.frame(Column1 = c(0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.8), Column2=c(20,40,50,90))

 Output <- data.frame(datetime=seq(as.POSIXct("2013-08-28 01:02:00"),
                                         length=4, by="1 hour"), Input)



 Output
 #            datetime Column1 Column2
 #1 2013-08-28 01:02:00     0.3      20
 #2 2013-08-28 02:02:00     0.5      40
 #3 2013-08-28 03:02:00     0.2      50
 #4 2013-08-28 04:02:00     0.8      90
```

Now, you can use `write.csv` or `write.table`

Comment: Can you tell me the way how to remove number 1,2,3,4 in first column in output Please...? I mean the output will have only 3 columns datetime, Column1 and Column2.

Comment: @Mon You can use `row.names=FALSE` in `write.table, also `quote=FALSE` if you don't want quotes.