# want to modify datetime stamp writing style in R

Tags: r, datetime

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26465505/4161531

Refer to my earlier question...i want to write datetime as 28/08/2013 01:00:00 here 
Can you help me how to do that ?

Comment: If you don't take the time to articulate your problem, do you really expect others to volunteer their time to articulate a solution?

Comment: I am not posting a question without trying my best..Thanks Anada mahto for your time..dont try solution if you dont want to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `format` (data from the link provided in the post)

```
  Output$datetime <- format(Output$datetime, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
  Output$datetime
  # [1] "28/08/2013 01:02:00" "28/08/2013 02:02:00" "28/08/2013 03:02:00"
  # [4] "28/08/2013 04:02:00"
```